# CRASH: A variable must be decoded with a `delegate` on iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

**There is a strange crash in iOS 10.0**

some console info:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', **reason: 'A variable must be decoded with a \`delegate\`'**

*** Assertion failure in -[NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeMarkerVariableToBeMinimized initWithCoder:], 

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1349/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISVariable.m:175
```

**more log console as shown in the picture.**

[image]

**I guess the problem is there: the line in which the red arrow points.**

`[HXDMineViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 168`

but there is no problem in iOS 9.0、8.0、7.0, except iOS 10.0.

I am completely at a lost. Anyone have this experience, and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you modified any file means rename any file out side the XCODE?

Comment: please add the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I haven't modified any file.

Comment: 1. first , dequeue cell ,  cell is customized by xib file, and already register ，when I open the Exceptiong BreakPoint, the breakpoint is stop  this line while crash.   `HXDMyPersonalInforCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HXDMyPersonalInforCellIndentify];`          2. second, do some configuration for cell. (pass model)